# Cleaned Wordpress From Malware But One of the website directory still has it

Tags: wordpress, malware

My website was hit with malware and as a result I did run virus scan built in with my hosting panel and also removed virus. I also changed FTP and wordpress passwords. Also added additional security through 2FA. However, when I am checking it with online scanner I see the virus in the following directory:

wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/js/um-gdpr.min.js?ver=2.6.11

However upon checking there is no such file in my wordpres directory there is one without ?ver=2.6.11. I contacted hosting and they said there is no such file. What can I do to get rid of this please guide.

I ran wordfence scan, did hosting built in scan, removed unknown files in the wordpress directory.

Comment: `?ver=2.6.11` is part of the URL - it's not reflected in the file on the disk. If this is indicated then check the file `um-gdpr.min.js`

Comment: I deleted this file you mentioned, but online malware scanners are still showing this. is min js file a compressed file?

Comment: Minified. Not sure if it's generated on request and cached or only generated based on `um-gdpr.js`

Comment: It is generated based on generated based on um-gdpr.js.